If $\mathcal{A'}$ is an algebra then $\mathcal{A}=\{A \cap E : A \in \mathcal{A'}\}$ is an algebra on $E.$
Let $\mathcal{A'}$ be an algebra on a non-empty set $X$ and $E \subset X$, then
$\mathcal{A}=\{A \cap E :  A \in \mathcal{A'}\}$ is an algebra on $E.$
I was able to show that;
$\mathcal{A}$ is closed under finite union and finite intersection.
I got confusion while proving the complementation. If $B$ is in $\mathcal{A}$, then $B^{c}$ is in $\mathcal{A}$.
But what is  $B^{c}$ here?
Is it $B^{c} = X-B$ or $B^{c}= E-B$ ?
Because $\mathcal{A}$ is to be an algebra on $E$ it has to be $B^{c}= E-B$.
I need to confirm! Thank you.

In this case $B^c=E-B$ since $B\subset E$ and you want to show that $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra on $E$. To show that $B^c \in \mathcal{A}$ you can observe that there exists $B'\in\mathcal{A'}$ so that $B=B'\cap A$. Therefore, $B'^c=X-B'\in \mathcal{A'}$, so $$B^c=E-B=E-(B'\cap E)=E-B'=(X-B') \cap E = B'^c\cap E \in \mathcal{A}.$$
